# Android Studio annotations setup

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm trying to use AndroidAnnotations in Android Studio.
What's difference between "store generated sources relative to **module output directory**" and "store generated sources relative to **module content root**"?

I searched in Intellij Idea manual but found nothing.

Comment: Are you using gradle?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using Gradle. In your `build.gradle`:

1) Configure the APT plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'your.package.here'
    }
}
```

2) Add the AA dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0"
compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0'
```

You can see the AndroidAnnotations generated classes in `build/generated/source/apt/debug/your.package.here`

Comment: The generated classes are actually in *build/generated/source/apt/debug*. Also you should add a *mavenCentral()* dependency repo, as it is not included by default.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways to get my project to build with Dagger2 and AA. What ended up solving my issue was having both

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' 
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

In the project gradle I have

```
 classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

In my app gradle file I have

```
def AAVersion = '4.2.0'
annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
```

This seems to be working. Previously I was getting the ClassNotDefError. Then I started to get an error about Dagger file not generating.

Hope this helps!